# What is wrong with my attempt to use a CASE statement in a computed column?

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm attempting to create a computed column that will find Region based on `State`.

Here's what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnDonorRegion (@Region VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE
           WHEN DONOR.[State] IN ('Connecticut', 'Maine', 'Massachusetts', 'New Hampshire', 'Rhode Island', 'Vermont', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'Pennsylvania') 
              THEN 'Northeast'
           WHEN DONOR.[State] IN ('Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Michigan', 'Ohio', 'Wisconsin', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri', 'Nebraska', 'North Dakota', 'South Dakota') 
              THEN 'Midwest'
           WHEN DONOR.[State] IN ('Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Maryland', 'North Carolina', 'South Carolina', 'Virginia', 'District of Columbia', 'West Virginia', 'Alabama', 'Kentucky', 'Mississippi', 'Tennessee', 'Arkansas', 'Louisiana', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas') 
              THEN 'South'
           ELSE 'West'
        END
END

ALTER TABLE tblDONOR
ADD Region AS fnDonorRegion
```

I keep getting the error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fnDonorRegion, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "D.State" could not be bound.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: where is your `from` clause?

Comment: where should it be? @SankarRaj

Comment: You are trying above against which database, is DONOR a table?

Comment: @deepakl it's a database my team and I created, DONOR is a table, and State is a column.

Comment: I think what you want to do is give a @region(state names) as a input and get the output as `Northeast` or `Midwest` or `west` or `south`. Am i right?

Comment: Is DONOR.[State] correct syntax, should it be DONOR.State ?

Comment: @deepakl I need the [ ] because State is a reserved keyword

Comment: In order to retrieve data from table, then you should use `SELECT` statement, syntax will be `SELECT...//list of cols//... FROM table_name`

Comment: [**Bad habits to kick** : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. In your case, since you're *not* declaring any length on the returned `varchar`, you're essentially returning `varchar(1)` - only ***ONE*** character long  - usually *not* what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the parameter not the table.  So let's assume the parameter is the state.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnDonorRegion (@state varchar(10))
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
  CASE
    WHEN @state  IN ('Connecticut', 'Maine', 'Massachusetts', 'New Hampshire', 'Rhode
        Island', 'Vermont', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'Pennsylvania') THEN 'Northeast'
    WHEN @state   IN ('Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Michigan', 'Ohio', 'Wisconsin',
      'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri', 'Nebraska', 'North Dakota', 'South Dakota') THEN 'Midwest'
    WHEN @state   IN ('Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Maryland', 'North Carolina',
      'South Carolina', 'Virginia', 'District of Columbia', 'West Virginia', 'Alabama', 'Kentucky',
      'Mississippi', 'Tennessee', 'Arkansas', 'Louisiana', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas') THEN 'South'
    ELSE 'West'
  END
END

ALTER TABLE tblDONOR
ADD Region AS fnDonorRegion([state]) -- assume your table has a column named state
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use your input variable in `CASE` statement.

```
Create FUNCTION fnDonorRegion (@Region varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
  CASE
    WHEN @Region IN ('Connecticut', 'Maine', 'Massachusetts', 'New Hampshire', 'Rhode
        Island', 'Vermont', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'Pennsylvania') THEN 'Northeast'
    WHEN @Region IN ('Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Michigan', 'Ohio', 'Wisconsin',
      'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri', 'Nebraska', 'North Dakota', 'South Dakota') THEN 'Midwest'
    WHEN @Region IN ('Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Maryland', 'North Carolina',
      'South Carolina', 'Virginia', 'District of Columbia', 'West Virginia', 'Alabama', 'Kentucky',
      'Mississippi', 'Tennessee', 'Arkansas', 'Louisiana', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas') THEN 'South'
    ELSE 'West'
  ENd
ENd

select dbo.fnDonorRegion('Mississippi')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnDonorRegion
    (@Region VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result  VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT 
        @Result= CASE
                    WHEN DONOR.[State] IN (@Region)
                       THEN 'Northeast'
                    WHEN DONOR.[State] IN(@Region)
                       THEN 'Midwest'                  
                    ELSE 'West'
                 END 
    FROM tblDONOR AS DONOR

    RETURN @Result  
 END;

SELECT dbo.fnDonorRegion('Connecticut')
```